# Printout the deftemplate information in java

Tags: java, jess

I am trying to print out the information stored into the recommendation(slot package)(slot explanation) deftemplate, from java after some rules have been fired in JESS. 
the part of code related to printing out the results is as followed :

```
Rete r = new Rete();
Iterator itt = r.listDeftemplates();
while(itt.hasNext()){
Deftemplate dt = (Deftemplate)itt.next();
String bn = dt.getBaseName();
dt.getSlotNames();
if(bn.equals("recommendation")){
System.out.println(dt.getSlotName(0));
System.out.println(dt.getSlotName(1));
System.out.println(bn);
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: so you dont see any output?

Comment: I can only print out the name of the slots, but not the contents which have been asserted to each slot after having the rules fired.

Comment: are you sure that dt.getSlotName(0) is the correct method call for this. looks like this method is designed to give you the name of the slot and not the content

Comment: Yes, I couldnt find the method to call the contents. thats what I need help for. Thanks

Comment: have you tried reading through the documentation? by the way, what does the Deftemplate class look like?

Comment: this is how the deftemplate has been defined as: (deftemplate recommendation
  (slot package)
  (slot explanation))

I have found anything in the document about this.

Comment: You must have overlooked Chapter 10, Introduction to Programming with Jess in Java. Although it doesn't contain a code snippet solving your problem, Rete.listFacts is mentioned, and from there the excellent Javadoc is easy to follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class Rete comes with an API that lets you investigate everything in a Rete object. Iterate the Fact objects, filter the ones you want, print the slot values:

```
Iterator itf = rete.listFacts();
while(itf.hasNext()){
    Fact fact = (Fact)itf.next();
    if( fact.getName().equals("MAIN::recommendation")){ 
    System.out.println( "package: " + 
                        fact.getSlotValue( "package" ));
    System.out.println( "explanation: " +
                        fact.getSlotValue( "explanation" ) );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Laune, You are so awesome